# Google Timeline: Force a finer-grained breakdown

Tags: google-maps

When I go to my college campus, Google Timeline just says I was at the college campus from 9 AM to 9 PM. However, the college campus spans several blocks and buildings. Ideally, it would say I was at building X from 9 AM to 10 AM, and then walked to building Y from 10 AM to 11 AM, and then went to restaurant Z from 11 AM to 12 PM, etc.

However, the fact that there's a college campus here seems to have blinded Google Timeline to the possibility of doing a finer breakdown. Is there any easy way to just tell it to go finer, instead of manually editing everything in?

Comment: You might get better location accuracy if you use Google Maps between activities. See the answers to [Can I improve accuracy of Google Location while hiking](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/229033/3573)

Comment: Can someone migrate this question back to Web Applications Stack Exchange? Not sure why it was migrated in the first place (there are already several questions on the former site about Google Timeline, and Google Timelines is not 
 necessarily an Android application -- in fact, I use it purely on iPhone and desktop).

Comment: @MorrisonChang to clarify, the location is being tracked accurately. If I click "edit" on the web UI, I can see my location bouncing around. It is the classification in Timelines which just regards this entire period of time in these locations as being 1 event instead of several different ones.

Comment: If the location is accurate, but the labelling is not then it is a Google issue, i.e. it doesn't recognize each building at your campus as a place of interest (POI) or not labeling your track as such even if the buildings are in the GMaps POI data set. At best send feedback either in Google Maps or where you are viewing Timeline.